# Dropdown List multiselection in yii2

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2, multi-select

I need multiselection in dropdown list. 
This my dropdown list

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'receiver_id')->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),'id','username'),
    ['prompt' => 'Select receiver...']
) ?>
```

But it's only for one receiver. I want to choose some receivers and display them in textfield of this list separated by commas. Could you help with this problem?
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: If you add `'multiple' => true` in the options for dropDownList you get multiselection but I'm not sure if this what you are looking for. Remember that field like this will become array and not string.

Comment: Hi, I tried it before and it's not my need. It trasforms into listbox by adding this option.

Comment: Yes, you are right about array,but I want to send the same message to different receivers by choosing them in dropdownlist. How can I implement this logic?

Answer (score 1):

just use a listbox

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'receiver_id')->listbox(
    ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),'id','username')
) ?>
```

or use a select2 widget by kartik

Comment: Yeap, I tried it also, but when I choose receivers by clicking I have to press   ctrl to choose some of them.

Comment: multiple select2 widget is that I want, thanks. Is there any method to use it with active form?

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
    echo $form->field($model, 'state_1')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => $data,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a color ...', 'multiple' => true],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'tags' => true,
            'maximumInputLength' => 10
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: <?= $form->field($model, 'receiver_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),'id','username'),
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select receivers...', 'multiple' => true],
        'pluginOptions' => [
        'tags' => true,
        'maximumInputLength' => 10
    ],
    ]); ?>

Form in view works fine, but the logic doesn't. I've got array to string conversion error as Bizley predicted. What can I do with it?

Comment: Yeap it is possible