# I need a multi selection on dropdown

Tags: php, yii2

I need multi selection on dropdown. There are dropdown

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'referal_id')->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),'id','fullname'),
    ['prompt' => 'Select Referal...']
) ?>
```

Comment: your question is same with it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812023/dropdown-list-multiselection-in-yii2/38812439#38812439
There are solved this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dropdown List multiselection in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812023/dropdown-list-multiselection-in-yii2)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'referal_id')->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),'id','fullname'),
    [
        'prompt' => 'Select Referal...',
        'multiple' => true //set this option
    ]
) ?>
```

And don't forget that your post will be array now. I supose that you store that information in another table so you'll have to set new property like `referals`, and change multiselect property with it. (`$form->field($model, 'referals')`)
After that just foreach it and save it like:

```
if($model->referals){
    foreach($model->referals as $user_id){
        //save in another table linked to $model->id
    }
}
```